# Source voltage driving a series LED strip seems below combined forward voltage

Tags: led, led-driver

I am currently working on a project to build a digital clock. The digits of the clock are to be made from custom-built seven-segment displays.

Each segment of a digit will be made up of a couple of LED strings (more than one LED in series per string) all hooked to the same switch. The LEDs are to be connected to a constant voltage source (NOT current controlled).

Poking around an old product (not mine), I noticed a design with the following characteristics of an LED string.

1. LED COLOR  =   White
2. No. of LED's per string  =  5
3. String series resistance = ~67 ohms
4. Source Voltage  =  12 V

This has got me a bit confused because the forward voltage of a white LED is almost always specified at about 3 V. This means for a 12 V system, you can have at most 4 LEDs per string (without the current limiting resistor).

Unfortunately for me, the [product](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32814675463.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.24da3812rZKNSQ&algo_pvid=aec5ac11-5cc3-4f8e-91c6-8b35a0ac6adb&algo_expid=aec5ac11-5cc3-4f8e-91c6-8b35a0ac6adb-0&btsid=0ab50f6115856104065578528ebb0c&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) I plan on sourcing does not come with a detailed datasheet.

So I would like to ask the community if I am missing something here, i.e.:

1. Are there white LEDs (regular price) with far lower rated forward voltage?
2. Can a 3 V rated LED be driven at lower voltages and not loose too much brightness?
3. Any recommended solutions for my project?

Comment: Correct, a white LED needs ~3 VDC. Is the supply from 12 VAC, though? P-P voltage is ~1.414 * 12, ~17 V P-P.

Comment: Back a few years ago I measured around 2.7V for white LEDs, and that was at full brightness. It wouldn't surprise me if some worked at 2.5V.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik You may be onto something! On the PCB board it said 12V in, but i will see if i can get access to the power supply to check.

Comment: @EdinFifić So confusing! Considering a switch to a 24V power supply for my sanity. But i think i will have to order some of these LED's to experiment on before i commit to a PCB

Comment: The simplest thing to do with LEDs is to drive them with a current source capable of giving them a voltage higher than they need, or using a higher voltage than calculated and then control the current with a resistor or a semiconductor type of current limiting/control. Trying to give them the exact voltage needed is like dancing around the pin of a needle because it varies between all LEDs, changes with temperature and small changes in voltage result in large changes in current.